# PHP with cookies parser is "cherry picking"

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

I have an issues with PHP not giving out all the cookies it's told to. It seems to be skipping them.

Here's the snippit:

```
setcookie("e_id", "$id", 0, "/", "", 0);
setcookie("company", "$location", 0, "/", "", 0);
setcookie("employ_name", "$name", 0, "/", "", 0);
setcookie("li_right", "$rights", 0, "/", "", 0);
setcookie("employ_onum", "$office_num", 0, "/"."", 0);
setcookie("employ_cell", "$cell_num", 0, "/", "", 0);
setcookie("employ_oemail", "$office_email", 0, "/", "", 0);
setcookie("employ_title", "$job_title", 0, "/", "", 0);
setcookie("firstrun", "$first_run", 0, "/", "", 0);
setcookie("attem", "$attem", 0, "/", "", 0);
setcookie("LOTO", "$locked_out", 0, "/", "", 0);
setcookie("secu", "$u_acct", 0, "/", "", 0);
setcookie("usr_pg", "$land_page", 0, "/", "", 0);
```

The only cookies loading is li_right and attem. there is data in the tables but it's not spitting up cookies. It seems weird that only a few will load.

Comment: Debug with Firebug or Liveheaders. Also, while I'm all pro-privacy and preserving readable cookies, this case looks like you should be using a session. That's not too many cookies by themselves, but might become. The general browser limit is 50 cookies per domain, after which others get discarded.

Answer (score 1):

Do all of the other variables have values? Have you watched the headers come down to the page to see if they're what you're expecting?

Comment: yes They all do. How would I watch the headers? it goes from a MySQL query to "$locked_out = stripslashes($info['locked_out']);" type array. So for the LOTO cookie it's $locked_out = stripslashes($info['locked_out']); to setcookie("LOTO", "$locked_out", 0, "/", "", 0); . But despite having data in the array, it's not loading the cookie. I'm wondering if it's a server issue at my hosting company, because I'm have problems uploading too.

Comment: You can use firebug or the tools that come with chrome, safari, or ie9 to watch the headers for the request come down. At that point you should be able to narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: I got most of the cookies. It was an issue with mysql query